# Составление SQL запроса

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, created_at
FROM lead
WHERE created_at >  '{$timestamp}'
AND api_partner = 1
GROUP BY DAY(created_at)
ORDER BY created_at ASC
```

где `{$timestamp}` - дата неделю назад.

Запрос выбирает из таблицы число записей, которые были созданы от недели назад до нынешнего момента, группирует их по дате. Выборка идет по столбцу `api_partner`, где значение может быть или `1`, или `2`.

Нужно выбрать из таблицы число записей по дням для `api_partner = 1` и `api_partner = 2`, и, если за какой-то день есть запись у одного из `api_partner`, но нет у другого - количество записей за день для `api_partner`, у которого нет записей за этот день, должно быть `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так :

```
SELECT 
  sum(case when api_partner=1 then 1 else 0 end) as p1_count,
  sum(case when api_partner=2 then 1 else 0 end) as p2_count,
  from_unixtime(created_at) 
FROM ttt 
WHERE 
   created_at >1438094000  
GROUP BY 
   day(from_unixtime(created_at)) 
ORDER BY 
   created_at ASC
```

Здесь created_at имеет тип INT и хранит unixtimestamp

Comment: Большое спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 2):

например, так (d — дата, p — номер партнёра):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a799/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (d date, p int);

insert into t values
   ('2015-08-01', 1)
  ,('2015-08-01', 2)
  ,('2015-08-02', 1)
  ,('2015-08-03', 2)
  ,('2015-08-04', 1)
  ,('2015-08-04', 2)
  ,('2015-08-04', 2)
;   

create view v as
  select distinct d as d, 1 as p
  from t
  union all
  select distinct d, 2
  from t;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
   date_format(v.d, '%Y-%m-%d') as d
  ,v.p
  ,if(t.p is null, 0, count(t.p)) as count
from v
left join t
  on t.d = v.d
  and t.p = v.p
where v.d > '2015-07-01'
group by v.d, v.p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a799/4/0)**:

```
|          d | p | count |
|------------|---|-------|
| 2015-08-01 | 1 |     1 |
| 2015-08-01 | 2 |     1 |
| 2015-08-02 | 1 |     1 |
| 2015-08-02 | 2 |     0 |
| 2015-08-03 | 1 |     0 |
| 2015-08-03 | 2 |     1 |
| 2015-08-04 | 1 |     1 |
| 2015-08-04 | 2 |     2 |
```